# How to have a widget-like entry in the Shortcuts app for my App Intents in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, shortcut, sirishortcuts, appintents

I refer to having the App Intents looking like these widgets inside the Shortcuts app. Is that possible or only reserved for Apple apps?

I thought it would be enough adding a shortTitle and systemImageName for the AppShortcuts returned in the AppShortcutsProvider but all I get are separate cards for each entry instead of the widget-like section.

[image]

Comment: Any update please

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an `AppShortcutProvider` for you intent. Providing a short title and systemImage will provide the image

For Example

```swift
struct TaskAppShortcutProvider: AppShortcutsProvider {
    static var appShortcuts: [AppShortcut] = [
    AppShortcut(intent: MarkTaskCompleteIntent(),
                phrases: ["Complete Tasks in \(.applicationName)"],
                shortTitle: "Complete Task",
                systemImageName: "checkmark"),
    AppShortcut(intent: AddTaskIntent(), phrases: ["Add task to \(.applicationName)"], shortTitle: "Add Task", systemImageName: "plus")
    
    ]
}
```